# Proof of Implication when Second Statement has Multiple Parts

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

This is something of a logic/proof question.  If you wish to show that A implies B but B involves four separate statements (along the lines of there exists a map such (i), (ii), (iii) and (iv) are all true), which of the following two do you need to show is true?

- A implies (i), A implies (ii), A implies (iii) and A implies (iv), separately
- A implies (i), (i) implies (ii), (ii) implies (iii), (iii) implies (iv) and finally, (iv) implies (i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overlap between the two strategies: the second strategy (even without the last step for "(iv) implies (i)") implies the first!

Here is why: if you can show that A implies (i), you have the first implication of the first bullet. If you also show that (i) implies (ii), then  A implies (i) which implies (ii), and thus you get that A implies (ii) which is the second implication of the first bullet. Similarly for (iii) and (iv).

So, either you succeed with the first strategy or with the second, you will have a proof that A implies B.

Something that may need care though is the map. If the four sub-statements of B all involve the same map, then you should make sure that each (sub)implication refers to the same map. Because, it is one thing to prove that "If A, then there exists a map such that (i) and (ii)", and it is a different thing to prove that "If A, then there exists a map such that (i) and there exists a (possibly different) map such that (ii)".